# Android start activity with onClickListener?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a home replacement application. I'm trying to add an `OnClickListener` to a button with Java but the way I'm trying produces error:

> The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

This code is inside adapter `MyPagerAdapter`.

This is what I am trying:

```
    buttonItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.contacts.ContactsApplication");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

How can I add an `OnClickListener` to a button that opens another application, like for example `com.android.contacts.ContactApplication`?

---

EDIT:
This is the full code, with what I am trying right now:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
        Context context = container.getContext();
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        TextView textItem = new TextView(context);
        Button buttonItem = new Button(context);
        buttonItem.setText("Aceptar");

        // This is what I'm trying, (crashes on click)
        buttonItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.contacts.ContactsApplication");
               v.getContext().startActivity(intent); 
            }
        });
```

Comment: What exactly is this code in? An Activity?

Comment: It's on the PagerAdapter.

Comment: Anyways, use `v.getContext().startActivity(intent);` to launch the application, and Grid's answer to make the intent properly. (Deleted the answer since it doesn't really serve a purpose).

Comment: thanks, it worked doing just that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 buttonItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.contacts", "com.android.contacts.DialtactsContactsEntryActivity"));
        i.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        i.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
        i.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
        v.getContext().startActivity(i);
    }
```

Comment: How is this supposed to help? Read his question.

Comment: @dymmeh That is the proper way to launch the contacts application.

Comment: @A--C - The intent wasn't in question. His answer included calling startActivity despite the question clearly stating that startActivity wasn't accessible in the current scope. His edits fixed all of that, though

Answer (score 1):

```
(findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), ACTIVITY.class));
    }
});
```