# the method startactivity(intent) is undefined for the type new view.onclicklistener()

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using **Eclipse** to Create Android Application 
I get the following error when compiler trying to execute `startActivity(callIntent);`

> the method startactivity(intent) is undefined for the type new
>   view.onclicklistener()

On the following my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{

       View vi = convertView;
         if (vi == null)
           vi = inflater.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.row_listview, null);              
       Button call_btn =(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.call_btn);
       call_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
           @Override
          public void onClick(View v) { 
               Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
               callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
               startActivity(callIntent); //error occurred here <-------
               notifyDataSetChanged();
         }
       });

       return vi;
   }
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: Might be a typo, but you have StartActivity(callIntent) when it should be startActivity(callIntent). Also, is this getView method in a Fragment or Activity, or an adapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is already answered in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266875/android-start-activity-with-onclicklistener)
`startActivity` is undefined for `onClickListener` so you need to use the parameter `View v`:

```
v.getContext().startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 3):

startActivity is only defined from Activity or Fragment,
you should try

`((Activity)v.getContext()).startActivity(intent);`

If you call from a View or Adapter of whatever.

If you call from the Activity's Java file,
try

`ActivityName.this.startActivity(intent);`

Comment: i prefer another question because startActivity() is a method on Context; you do not need to cast it to Activity...any way thanks

Answer (score 2):

First, the method is named `startActivity()`, not `StartActivity()`. Java is a case-sensitive programming language.

Second, use `ThisIsYourActivityName.this.startActivity()`, where `ThisIsYourActivityName` is the name of the activity class in which this code resides. This assumes that your code snippet above is from an activity; if it is not, please edit your question to provide **all** the code from this Java class.

Comment: thanks , it is work i am on adapter so i used ((Activity)v.getContext()).startActivity(intent);

Comment: @MohamadMahmoud: `startActivity()` is a method on `Context`; you do not need to cast it to `Activity`.